# Python/MySQL: Using %s in a pythonic manner instead of a mysql.connector manner in an INSERT statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql, connector

I am trying to write a script that reads a tab delimited text file and first creates a mysql table and then inserts the data into that table. 
Problem: I'm stuck on writing the INSERT query because %s placeholder serves a new purpose with the mysql.connector API. Here is my code:

```
def insertmanyquery(tabletitle, headers, values):
   '''connects to a mysql database and inserts a list of tab delimited   rows into a table'''
   cnxn = connect(all the connection parameters)
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   numofvalues = r"%s, " * len(headers.split(','))
   numofvalues = numofvalues[:-2]
   query = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (tabletitle, headers, numofvalues)
   cursor.executemany(query,values)
   cnxn.commit()
   cursor.close()
   cnxn.close()
```

This would hopefully allow the insert query to adapt to however many columns are present in the table.

If I call the function as follows:

```
tabletitle = 'Bikes'
headers = 'BikeBrand, BikeName, Purpose, Price, YearPurchased'
values = ['Norco', 'Range', 'Enduro', 8,000.00, 2018]
insertmanyquery(tabletitle, headers, values)
```

I get the following error: *mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement*

If I just print the query instead of executing it, it looks fine:
*INSERT INTO Bikes (BikeBrand, BikeName, Purpose, Price, YearPurchased) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)*

I believe I am getting this error because the third %s in my INSERT query is being interpreted as a part of the connector INSERT syntax instead of first being interpreted in a pythonic manner and then being interpreted as connector syntax.

I am very new to coding so maybe I'm approaching this all wrong, regardless, I'd like to hear potential solutions to this problem or better ways to code this.

Thank you for your time

UPDATE:

I have tried making the query `query = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)" % (tabletitle, headers) + " VALUES (" + numofvalues +");"` and I still get the same error! so it doesn't have to do with using the placeholder.. >.<

Comment: You should not be using string formatting here at all. As you acknowledge, `%s` serves a different purpose with the mysql API, and for good reason. It's a placeholder for values which helps against SQL injection. You will want to look into parameterized queries.

Comment: Why don't you `print(query)` and see what you are actually executing? You do want to make this safer by using prepared statement. Example here: https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/ I don't like the fact that they name their var input.

Comment: *I believe this is because the third %s in my INSERT query is being interpreted as a part of the connector INSERT syntax*: no, that's not true. All `%s` in your original template string have been replaced with new strings. You simply appear to have a values list that is *longer* than the number of headers. Did you forget to split the values string perhaps?

Comment: You don't show what `headers` or `values` are, so we can't actually help here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the test table I'm using has five headers: headers = 'BikeBrand, BikeName, Purpose, Price, YearPurchased' and five values: values = ['Norco', 'Range', 'Enduro', 8,000.00, 2018]

Comment: @roganjosh yes I'm aware that that is probably the problem, I'm not sure how else to do it though... how to construct the query that is adaptable to different sized tables/different number of columns. The API just happens to use the exact same syntax as python's for placeholders

Comment: @Leonid I have done this. Query looks fine. I just removed that print statement for this post. The query looks like this if printed and not executed: INSERT INTO MarcsBikes (BikeBrand, BikeName, Purpose, Price, YearPurchased) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)

Comment: @Sara, that query would need quotes (single, I think) around each string value that you are inserting (inside values). You also did not expand enough %s apparently - probably need to supply the actual values as well.

Comment: @Leonid Thank you for answering. I've edited the question above to provide more information (including the values). Right now I just tried adding quotes around my integer values to make them strings, still same error. Then I tried using just one %s (not expanding it) in the query as follows:`query = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)" % (tabletitle, headers) + " VALUES (%s)" ` and I got the same error again

Comment: Try this without calling the function but immediately after the three params are defined: `query = ("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (tabletitle, headers, values)).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')`. It is a sily hack but it would work. Again, it creates SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Before I do this, could explain what exactly the purpose of this is? The parameterized query for an INSERT uses a list for its values. Why and where am I removing square brackets?